# how to get the previous script after modification of sp in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I`ve altered a procedure without backup, now I want previous script back .
Is there any way to get it again?

Answer (score 5):

No, there isn't, not easily anyways. You *could* try looking at the [transaction logs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6740078/1583).

Without a backup or other place where you hold versions of the stored procedure, you can't get it back.

Check your test/dev systems - you may be lucky and a prior version may still be lingering somewhere.

In the future - keep all database scripts in [source control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) so such issues can be avoided.