# SQL Server stored overwritten,ow can I recover/roll-back this store procedure to its original state..?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, restore

Database:                SQL Server 2012
Name of Store Procedure: dbo.sp_ins_output_str
Date overwritten:        2014-06-26 (yesterday)

I have a SQL Server stored procedure thats overwritten by accident and executed, how can I recover/roll-back this store procedure to its original state..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739949/undo-changes-to-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 0):

There's no "Undo Button" per se, but you can get it back using the following method.

1. Restore the database to a different location, recovering to a time
   prior to the alter being executed
2. Extract the DDL of that SP from the restored location
3. Alter the current erroneous SP using the DDL taken in Step 2
4. Drop the restored database
5. Feel heart rate decrease

Though if you have no backup, you're out of luck unless you have a [CVS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrent_Versions_System) that contains all your DDL.